# Are Certain EC2 Instance Types Provisioned Faster than Others?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

During development, we create and destroy EC2 instances with abandon.  What we're wondering is: will we save developer time (waiting for instances to be provisioned) by favoring certain instance types (say, `m4.large`) over others (say, `m4.xlarge`)?

Searched the web and didn't find any EC2 *creation* benchmarks, only performance benchmarks.

Our own empirical experience is that the instance type is not a significant influence in creation time, but we don't completely trust our shamefully unscientific (read: lazy) methods.

Hoping someone with insight into EC2 internals, or with more rigorous data and experience than ours, might weigh in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provisioning time is going to be dominated by factors outside your control: mostly the load on Amazon's systems. Much more than fluctuations on provisioning time, I've found the most frustrating thing is provisioning failures. Sometimes Amazon sells out of an instance type for some time (minutes, usually) and any scripted provisioning requests fail with errors.

You can reduce the chance of provisioning failure from contention by asking for unpopular instance types. This is not so fun, though.

Comment: Thanks. We haven't run into provisioning failures (yet), but I'm looking forward to it. Btw how does one learn the popularity of various instance types?